# Octave does not install: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: ubuntu-studio, octave

I am using Ubuntu Studio 16.10 64 bit and trying to install octave3.6.3

```
  wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.6.3.tar.bz2
    tar -xvf octave-3.6.3.tar.bz2
    cd octave-3.6.3
    ./configure
```

I got

```
 checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for style of include used by make... GNU
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    ...........

    make
    make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

We wonder why you are trying to install a circa-2012 version of *octave* when much newer versions are available. In fact, a 16.10 compatible version exists in the Ubuntu repositories. Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Comment: Yup I tried that first and when I typed octave at the command prompt, I got the error message "The settings file
/home/prasad/.config/octave/qt-settings
does not exist and can not be created.
Make sure you have read and write permissions to
/home/prasad/.config/octave

Octave GUI must be closed now."

Comment: Please see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292721/error-running-octave-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the configure stage  (before make) , you might have some error message indicating missing dependency (so you must install some devel packages)
If you are lucky, missing packages will be installed  running `apt-get build-dep octave` before "./configure" .

Edit:
   Run this:
`sudo apt-get install f2c gfortran libblas-dev liblapack-dev libpcre3-dev libreadline-dev`

(taken from  [here](https://coderwall.com/p/wo8dkw/ubuntu-installing-octave-fortran-77-error) )

Comment: checking how to get verbose linking output from ... configure: WARNING: compilation failed

checking for Fortran 77 libraries of ... 
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... configure: error: in `/home/prasad/octave-3.6.3':
configure: error: cannot compile a simple Fortran program
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: I tried sudo apt- build-dep octave and got he following message "E: Unable to find a source package for octave"